# Using $.each in AJAX Success Callback

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the following console.log(data):
`[{"optionPropertyID":"287","optionID":"106","optionBedrooms":"2","optionSleeps":"1","optionDescription":"1"},{"optionPropertyID":"287","optionID":"105","optionBedrooms":"2","optionSleeps":"1","optionDescription":"1"}]`

I am trying to use this data in a $.each function inside my AJAX success callback but it continually errors out on me:

```
success:function(data){
       alert(data);
       console.log(data);
       $.each(data, function(){
    alert("ID: " + this.optionID);
});
           },
```

I receive the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator ...

In doing some research on the error I need to use $.getJSON ?  But I am using an $.ajax call to get this data in the first place ...  little confused ..

I just want to iterate through this returned data and create fields for each piece of data.

```
input type="text" value="'+this.optionID+'"
```

Im just trying to alert the data back currently to ensure it is looping through.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: you need to specify datatype json in ajax. check datatype --  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ -- when used you will see an oblect in the console not the text as you have

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and explanation

Comment: `$.getJSON` is a helper shortcut function to `$.ajax` that automatically parses json responses. just use this `var data = JSON.parse(data);`. for future reference, please learn to use google and the search feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the option:

```
dataType: "json",
```

to the `$.ajax` call. This tells it to parse the JSON automatically.

Alternatively, the server script could use

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

Answer (score 1):

Because it is raw text. data in callback is always raw text when received.

You must make `Object` from it to use with `$.each`. You can do this with [`jQuery.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

```
success:function(data){
       var dataObject = $.parseJSON(data);
       $.each(dataObject, function(){
    alert("ID: " + this.optionID);
});
           },
```

Answer (score 0):

if your returning an object in other way around please try below code. this works for me. hopes this help.

```
success : function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function( index, value ) {
                         var sampleId = value.optionPropertyID;
                          ...
                        });
                    }
```